# How long does it usually take bintray to sync to jcenter?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have uploaded my library here:
https://bintray.com/cuipengfei/maven/autoupdateapk

It has been approved to link to jcenter yesterday.

I can even get search results in jcenter: https://bintray.com/search?query=autoupdateapk

But when I add the library as dependency in gradle, gradle can not find it:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_upgradeDebugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.autoupdateapk:autoupdateapk:1.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/autoupdateapk/autoupdateapk/1.0.3/autoupdateapk-1.0.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/autoupdateapk/autoupdateapk/1.0.3/autoupdateapk-1.0.3.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/autoupdateapk/autoupdateapk/1.0.3/autoupdateapk-1.0.3.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/autoupdateapk/autoupdateapk/1.0.3/autoupdateapk-1.0.3.jar
```

If I add new repository in gradle:

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/cuipengfei/maven' }
```

Then it'll work. Which means it'll clearly already up there, just not synced to jcenter.

And also, I can find it here: http://dl.bintray.com/cuipengfei/maven/com/autoupdateapk/
But not here: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/autoupdateapk

So how long does it usually take bintray to sync to jcenter? Or did I miss some steps that prevented the binaries from syncing?

Comment: The files can be found now in jcenter. Notice that gradle tries to resolves a .jar while you have an .aar

Comment: What ended up being the solution?  I am running into the same issue and it's been over a day

Comment: @TimNuwin, I just waited